# How can I add divs to existing div correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating a page which displays data from database as `div` elements. At the beginning, I want to show all the data and them if the user types something in the form, then presented data will fit into the user search result.

I'm using `AJAX` technique.

The code is not working in the desired way because there is no `div` on the screen. I think that it is something to do with the declaration of `div` but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.?

```
<script> 


    function getData1(search)
    {

        if(search=="")
        {

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
             {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    fill1(data);

                }
            }; 

            xmlhttp.open("GET",'ex2.php?q=0', true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
        else
        {

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
             {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    fill1(data);

                }
            }; 

            xmlhttp.open("GET",'ex2.php?q='+search, true);
            xmlhttp.send();



        }

    }

    function fill1(data)
    {

        parent = document.getElementById('contener');
        parent.innerHTML = "";


        for(i=0, len =data.length; i<len; i++)
        {


            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = '<div class="tile" id='+data[i][0]+' onClick="detail(this.id)">


                                        +'<div class="date"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>'+data[i][3]+'</div>'
                                        +'<div class="features">'

                                            +'<div id="distance" class="sq">'

                                                +'<div class="img"><i class="icon-distance"></i></div>'
                                                +'<div class="description">'+data[i][1]+' km</div>'
                                                +'<div style="clear:both"></div>'

                                            +'</div>'
                                            +'<div id="time" class="sq">'

                                                +'<div class="img"><i class="icon-time"></i></div>'
                                                +'<div class="description">'+data[i][2]+'</div>'
                                                +'<div style="clear:both"></div>'

                                            +'</div>'
                                            +'<div id="velocity" class="sq">'

                                                +'<div class="img"><i class="icon-velocity"></i></div>'
                                                +'<div class="description">'+data[i][4]+' km/h</div>'
                                                +'<div style="clear:both"></div>'

                                            +'</div>'
                                            +'<div style="clear:both"></div>'

                                        +'</div>'

                                    +'</div>';


            parent.append(div);

        }


    }


    $('document').ready(getData1(""));

</script>
```

HTML part

```
<div id="contener"></div>
<div id="search">

    <form>

        <input type="text" onkeyup="getData(this.value)">

    </form>

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: It's `$(document).ready(getData1)`

Comment: it's not the solution

Comment: adeneo is suggesting the correct the way you can attach handler function with document.ready , did you try that ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help

Comment: Okay, first of all, the whole flow of your JS file is incorrect as I agree with @Deep that you should use document.ready, define your functions outside the document.ready function and call them from inside the document.ready function. Moreover the way you are creating AND then adding DIVS to your outer most div is incorrect. You should use the "fragment" property in Javascript to do the same.

Comment: Tell me what exactly do you want to achieve eventually?? Is it like you are submitting some data in the form using ajax call and then based on the response of what you receive in the success function you want to add divs.? Is that what you want to do??

Comment: Yes, it is what i want to achieve

Comment: There were some typos and `.ready()` expects a function. I have corrected your code. Please see below. Hope it will help. Now it is only giving me failed ajax due to the link. I hope it will work fine at your side now.

Comment: Stringified html is a terrible idea when adding a composed element. "Dynamic"-ify it and you will get better results. Since jquery seems to be used, why not using its features to append items?

Comment: So how can i create this divs in proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First thing first.**

You are calling a `getData()` function on `onkeyup="getData(this.value)"`where as in `script tag` you have a function named `getData1()`. There is a typo I guess.

> First change this `onkeyup="getData(this.value)"` to
>   `onkeyup="getData1(this.value)"`

Moreover, You are calling a function without `terminotor` in statement `$('document').ready(getData1(""));` it should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        getData1('');
});
```

**And lastly, you are missing a ending `apostrophe`**

```
div.innerHTML = '<div class="tile" id='+data[i][0]+' onClick="detail(this.id)">
```

it should be

```
 div.innerHTML = '<div class="tile" id='+data[i][0]+' onClick="detail(this.id)">'
```

---

Comment: I corrected this mistakes but the programm still do not works. The divs are not appearing in the 'contener' div

Comment: @W.Kurek , can you simply write a console.log("It's here..!! ") in your fill1(data) function to check whether that function is getting called or not. And then also console.log(len) to check the length of data, whether there is actually any data in the 'data' so that the 'for' loop is running or not. Check it and then tell me what results do you see on your console in your browser.

Comment: Can you see the console for errors ? It can be done by pressing `F10` key when on `browser`. And afterwards clicking `console tab`. And please state what error are you getting. Because divs will only render if your ajax is successful. Thank you

Comment: Or just for simplicity add this line `console.log(data)` just after `data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);` and see is there anything in it.

Comment: Yea, I agree with @Amkhan , if your Ajax call is not returning a success response, then no div will be added. So check your console for errors. If no errors, then check whether the console.log statements are getting printed or not.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

it's simpler,
an example

```
$.ajax({
      url: "yourActionUrl",
      data: {name: value},
      type: "GET"
      }).success(function(result){
             $("#search").html(result);
      }
```

Comment: Is the problem really about the AJAX declaration?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use jQuery, you can simply do something on these lines -

```
//Loop this for all the data you receive
$("#container").append("<div class='..'>{Everything you need}</div>");
```

And are you sure your AJAX is returning data? It could be a problem with that too. Check for the data returned by the AJAX call and post what you get here.